# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{a_2}{a_3}+\frac{a_3}{a_4}+...+\frac{a_n}{a_1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{a_2}{a_3}+\frac{a_3}{a_4}+...+\frac{a_n}{a_1}\right)$ if {$a_n$} is random sequence with positive terms.

If sequence is increasing ($a_1>a_2>...>a_n$), then $L=+\infty$
What is the limit when sequence is decreasing?

Answer (score 23):

**Hint**

Using  **AM $\ge$ GM inequality**, we get that
$\left(\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{a_2}{a_3}+\frac{a_3}{a_4}+...+\frac{a_n}{a_1}\right) \ge n$. Can you conclude now?

**Note:** Monotonicity of given sequence is unimportant here.